# Pandas count same/different columns

Tags: pandas, count

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Id          City     Color   City_1   Color_1
123         Miami    Nan     Miami    Nan
124         Miami    nan     Nan      Miami
125         Seattle  Nan     Mexico   Nan
126         Nan      white   Nan      Yellow
127         Wash     Nan     Wash     Nan
128         LA       pink    LA       Pink
```

(to recreate):

```
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Id': {0: 123, 1: 124, 2: 125, 3: 126, 4: 127, 5: 128},
 'City': {0: 'Miami', 1: 'Miami', 2: 'Seattle', 3: nan, 4: 'Wash', 5: 'LA'},
 'Color': {0: 'Nan', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 'white', 4: nan, 5: 'pink'},
 'City_1': {0: 'Miami', 1: nan, 2: 'Mexico', 3: nan, 4: 'Wash', 5: 'LA'},
 'Color_1': {0: nan, 1: 'Miami', 2: nan, 3: 'Yellow', 4: nan, 5: 'Pink'}})
```

I have to compare columns, ignoring Nans and add a same/different column to the dataset- and later need to output counts of same and counts of different

Output dataset should looks like this

```
Id          City     Color   City_1   Color_1      Result
123         Miami    Nan     Miami    Nan          Same
124         Miami    nan     Nan      Miami        Different   
125         Seattle  Nan     Mexico   Nan          Different
126         Nan      white   Nan      Yellow       Different
127         Wash     Nan     Wash     Nan          Same
128         LA       pink    LA       Pink         Same
```

wondering how to compare, ignoring the Nans

Comment: if you post the output of `df.to_dict()`, we can recreate your data for testing directly.  I missed the `nan` issue because they were cast to string copy/pasting from above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First repalce missing values to same values, e.g. `missing` and then compare lowercase values - if only 2 columns is possible use [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1 = df.fillna('missing')
m = df1['City'].str.lower().eq(df1['City_1'].str.lower()) & 
    df1['Color'].str.lower().eq(df1['Color_1'].str.lower())
df['Result'] = np.where(m, 'Same','Different')
print (df)
    Id     City  Color  City_1 Color_1     Result
0  123    Miami    NaN   Miami     NaN       Same
1  124    Miami    NaN     NaN   Miami  Different
2  125  Seattle    NaN  Mexico     NaN  Different
3  126      NaN  white     NaN  Yellow  Different
4  127     Wash    NaN    Wash     NaN       Same
5  128       LA   pink      LA    Pink       Same
```

Or if there is multiple columns like `City, City_1, City_2, City_N` use general solution:

```
f = lambda x: x.str.lower()
df11 = df.filter(like='City').apply(f).fillna('missing')
df22 = df.filter(like='Color').apply(f).fillna('missing')
m1 = df11.eq(df11.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)
m2 = df22.eq(df22.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)
df['Result'] = np.where(m1 & m2, 'Same','Different')
print (df)
    Id     City  Color  City_1 Color_1     Result
0  123    Miami    NaN   Miami     NaN       Same
1  124    Miami    NaN     NaN   Miami  Different
2  125  Seattle    NaN  Mexico     NaN  Different
3  126      NaN  white     NaN  Yellow  Different
4  127     Wash    NaN    Wash     NaN       Same
5  128       LA   pink      LA    Pink       Same
```

Answer (score 4):

Nans have some surpising properties such as `bool(np.nan == np.nan) = False` - this is probably the issue you're running into.

If you wish them to evaluate as equal, you can either cast them as string or use `fillna` and fill them with the same value everywhere.  Since the other response covered the `fillna` route, I'll cast as string here:

```
df["Result"] = ((df.City.astype(str) == df.City_1.astype(str)) & (df.Color.astype(str).str.lower() == df.Color_1.astype(str).str.lower())).map({True:"Same", False:"Different"})
```

result:

```
    Id     City  Color  City_1 Color_1     Result
0  123    Miami    Nan   Miami     NaN       Same
1  124    Miami    NaN     NaN   Miami  Different
2  125  Seattle    NaN  Mexico     NaN  Different
3  126      NaN  white     NaN  Yellow  Different
4  127     Wash    NaN    Wash     NaN       Same
5  128       LA   pink      LA    Pink       Same
```

None of the operations on existing columns happens in-place and won't be modified; only `Result` is created.  Note I've used `Pink.lower() == pink` to reproduce your expected results.